# How do you model a ground plane to match the height of a premade object?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm working on a minigolf course modeling project and have created a sample hole for testing purposes. Right now, the only ground  that I have is a flat plane on the axis.

[image: Top Down View]

The hole varies in height at some places, so the ground plane does not meet it except for the very bottom portion. How can I model the plane such that it matches the height of the hole?
[image: Side View]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just subdivide your plane and in edit mode activate proportional editing then just drag the vertices or faces to whatever height you want then in object mode shade it smooth for nicer look. Look at some modeling tutorials online it will help you a lot.

Comment: Yep. This, plus vertex snapping while constraining to the Z axis. Adjust the influence radius and experiment with various falloff curves to see which gives the most desirable result.